# Excel formula that returns address of cell's immediate precedent?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

How can I return the address of a cell's direct precedent? And use it in a formula, such as OFFSET() or IF()?

i.e.:

- Cell with address of C1 points to cell D30 (either on the same sheet, or another one in the same workbook)
- **CELL(C1)** returns C1, not D30, **INDEX(C1)** returns the value of C1.
- **Range("C1").DirectPrecedent** should work, but I can't seem to get it into any working format.

I tried making a function:

---

```
Function DirectPrecedent(rng As Range)
    Range(rng).DirectPrecedents
End Function
```

Which also doesn't seem to work (but I don't know VBA so I'm not surprised there).

So, what can I do to get something usable like:

- `OFFSET(DirectPrecedentOf(C1),0,3)` -- the cell 3 columns to the right of D30
- or: `IF(DirectPrecedentOf(C1)=TODAY(),"YES","NO")` -- If D30=today's date, return "YES"

Is this possible, whether C1 points to D30, or to 'Sheet2'!D30 ?

EDIT: It's been suggested I clarify WHY I need this, so here's more info:

```
B1: OFFSET(DirectPrecedentOf(C1),0,3)
C1: 'Sheet2'!D30
'Sheet2'!D30:D40: List of dates
'Sheet2'!G30:G40: List of dollar amounts
```

Basically,  I want something like "In column C, put date from column 'Sheet2'!D, In cell B1, put value from the cell three cells right of whichever cell is called in column C"

Comment: `Range(C1).DirectPrecedent` - such function / property doesn't exist in Excel, why do you use it? Do you have a module / add-in which implements it? Also there can be multiple cells referred in a formula, which one do you want to use in this case?

Comment: What you're looking for is generally managed through VLOOKUP or INDEX & MATCH, e.g. `VLOOKUP(C1,Sheet2!D30:G40,4,false)`

Comment: @MátéJuhász  `Range("range").DirectPrecedents` does exist, in VBA.  I'm trying to find some way to use it in a formula, or find some other way that gives the same result.   I'll look at VLOOKUP though, thank you!

Comment: To return a value in a function in VBA you assign the return value to the function name that is use "direct precedent=range(c1).directprecedents"

Answer (score 2):

*As per my knowledge there is no such formula is Excel, could return Precedent & Dependent cell address*.

But  I can suggest you VBA code which finds the Precedent as the OP.

**NB:** After you execute this code check the Immediate Window in VBA Editor for Cell address of Precedent.

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
Dim rngToCheck As Range
Dim rngPrecedents As Range
Dim rngPrecedent As Range

Set rngToCheck = Range("A2:A10")

On Error Resume Next
Set rngPrecedents = rngToCheck.Precedents
On Error GoTo 0

If rngPrecedents Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print rngToCheck.Address(External:=True) & _
                "Range has no precedents"
Else
    For Each rngPrecedent In rngPrecedents
        Debug.Print rngPrecedent.Address(External:=True)
    Next rngPrecedent
End If
```

End Sub

**Note** Excel will search Precedents for Data Range A2:A10, you can set as your need.

**Hope this help you. I've posted this Solution, after it has been tested by me.**